# How to change the value of 'mutiplier' property of NSLayoutConstarint in iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, adaptive-ui, adaptive-layout

I use Adaptive layout features for designing an app. I take a `IBOutlet` of an "Aspect Ratio" constraint . I want to change the value of this Aspect Ratio Value to the double of current value. The problem is that "`constraint`" property can be set easily from Code, but "`multiplier`" property is read only property.  For Aspect Ratio Change, "multipier" value change is necessary . How Could I do this?.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leftImageWidthAspectRatio;
```

In code

```
NSLog(@"cell.leftImageWidthAspectRatio:%@ : %lf  %lf",cell.leftImageWidthAspectRatio, cell.leftImageWidthAspectRatio.constant,cell.leftImageWidthAspectRatio.multiplier);
```

Results that

```
 cell.leftImageWidthAspectRatio:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c9f2ed0 UIView:0x7c9f2030.width == 2*RIFeedThumbImageView:0x7c9f2c90.width> : 0.000000  2.000000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re right—changing the multiplier on an existing constraint isn’t supported. `constant` is the exception, not the rule. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/constant):

> Unlike the other properties, the constant can be modified after constraint creation. Setting the constant on an existing constraint performs much better than removing the constraint and adding a new one that's exactly like the old except that it has a different constant.

What you need to do is what’s described at the end there: replace the existing constraint with an identical-but-with-a-different-multiplier one. Something like this should work:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *oldConstraint = cell.leftImageWidthAspectRatio;
CGFloat newMultiplier = 4; // or whatever
NSLayoutConstraint *newConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:oldConstraint.firstItem attribute:oldConstraint.firstAttribute relatedBy:oldConstraint.relation toItem:oldConstraint.secondItem attribute:oldConstraint.secondAttribute multiplier:newMultiplier constant:oldConstraint.constant];
newConstraint.priority = oldConstraint.priority;
[cell removeConstraint:oldConstraint];
[cell addConstraint:newConstraint];
```

Note that `cell` may be the wrong view for this—it depends where IB decides to put the original constraint. If that doesn’t work, dig up through the superviews of the constrained views (you can check what constraints they have with the `constraints` property) until you find where it’s ending up.

Answer (score -1):

An easy solution of this problem , I find like that

1. Take an another constraint  for Width
2. Change Priority for Aspect Ratio (less than Width Constraint Priority);
3. Change the width Constraint Value with the help of Aspect Ratio `multipile` property

`@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leftImagewidthConstaint;`

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leftImageWidthAspectRatio;
```

In code

```
cell.leftImageWidthAspectRatio.priority=500;
    cell.leftImagewidthConstaint.constant =cell.leftImagewidthConstaint.constant*cell.leftImageWidthAspectRatio.multiplier;
```

This works successfully